# how to use php preg_match() to detect illegal characters when given only legal characters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a set of characters that are allowed in a string of text. Is it possible to use preg_match to detect the existence of characters outside of the range of provided characters?

for example:

```
$str1 = "abcdf9"
$str2 = "abcdf@"
$str3 = "abcdfg"
```

legal chars = "a-z"

if (preg_match() ... ) needs to return false for '$str1' & '$str2', but 'tru' for $str3.

Will this be possible?

Comment: Yes. It's possible. `/[^a-z]/`

Comment: What @MarcB says, but invert the test -- this will return true if there is an illegal character in the input text

Comment: the test IS inverted. that'll match anything that ISN'T a-z. That's what the `^` is doing.

Comment: hmmm... thanks! I thought ^ means "start of line" the whole time according to Rubular.com reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!preg_match('/[^a-z]/', $string)) { //only a-z found }

//or

if(preg_match('/[^a-z]/', $string)) {
    return false; // other stuff found
} else {
    return true; // only a-z found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this site very usefull to deploy your regEx

http://regexr.com/

What do you need is /[a-z]/ ?

You can specify the number of chars with /[a-z]{5}/